# How to get Standardvalues from Sitecore GraphQL

Tags: jss, graphql

I am trying to get the sortorder value from Sitecore GraphQL and it is not recognizing the field. Any config needs to be updated ? Am i missing some thing here?

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: It's not working on my side. GraphQL query: <pre> item(path: "/sitecore/content/Home", language: "en") { children { results { id name field(name: "__sortorder") { sortorder: value } } } }
</pre>
But it's returning null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this GraphQL query to get all Fields of an Item:

```
query DemoQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  contextItem: item(path: $contextItem) {
     fields  {
        name
        value
     }
  }
}
```

You can use somethings like this to get the __sortorder Field:

```
query DemoQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  contextItem: item(path: $contextItem) {
    id
    field(name  : "__sortorder") {
       sortorder: value
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer.